# In Haskell, how to distinguish mutable references vs regular variables in monadic functions definitions

Tags: haskell, immutability, state-monad

Let's say you want to write some stateful function in Haskell.
You have to use a monadic style like this: (using whatever state monad)

```hs
f :: x -> k -> (ST s) r
```

So this means that essentially the function takes some input `x` and `k`, might use and/or modify the world to compute a return value `r`.

Assume `x` is a stateful structure, that might be modified by `f`. Assume `k` is just a simple key type used for example to access something in `x`. `k` itself will be assigned a simple number type later, but we don't want to have to decide now of its type.

So essentially I know that `x` is a mutable thing, and `k` is immutable.
The problem is just looking at `f`'s signature, we cannot tell that, so if `f` occurs in the body of some more complex monadic code we can't reason very well about those variables.

Example:

```hs
g :: x -> k -> (ST s) r
g a i = do
    ...
    f a i --  I don't know if i :: k depends on state
    ... --- I don't know if i was changed by f
```

What I mean is that if I was given a variable `i` of unknown type `k`, I don't know whether or not it depends on `s` and whether its value can be affected by a call of `f`.
This problem of course does not exist when writing pure functions, since everything is immutable.

Is there a way to conveniently annotate and, more importantly, statically enforce that `k` will remain unchanged in the ST monad when calling `f`?

Comment: You might want to use an effect system and separate reading and writing mutable references into two different effects.

Comment: All variables are immultable. A `ST` is not a state, it is a *change* of state.

Comment: OK i think I'm getting confused. Because a is immutable and its internals might change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `ST`, you can definitely tell what is mutable: an `Int` is always an immutable integer, while a `STRef s Int` is an (immutable) reference to a mutable `Int`.

Hence,

```
f :: STRef s Int -> String -> (ST s) Bool
```

can (read and) modify the `Int` pointed to the first argument, but can only read the immutable string passed as second argument.

On top of that, `f` might create (and mutate) new `STRef s` references to newly allocated values. It can also modify other valued if `f` was defined using a reference to such values. E.g. in

```
bar :: forall s . ST s ()
bar = do
   x_ref <- newSTRef "hello"
   let f :: STRef s String -> String -> ST s ()
       f y_ref str = do
         y <- readSTRef y_ref
         writeSTRef x_ref y
         writeSTRef y_ref (y ++ " change " ++ str)
   ...
```

calling `f` will alter both the string which was originally set to `"hello"` and the string whose reference is passed to `f`.

In your own example:

```
g :: x -> k -> (ST s) r
g a i = do
    ...
    f a i --  I don't know if i :: k depends on state
    ... --- I don't know if i was changed by f
```

If `i :: k` was not a reference, it still has the same value. If it was a reference, the referred value might have been changed by `f a i`.

Comment: is there a way to constrain the type ```k``` in the function signature to make it explicit that it cannot depend on ```s``` ?

Comment: @jam If it does not explicitly depend on `s`, it can not be modified. E.g. `f :: forall a s . Maybe a -> ST s ()` can not alter the first argument, not even if the caller passes `Just ref` where `ref :: STRef s Int`.

Comment: I disagree. You can plug in something that happens to depend on ```s``` even if there is no explicit ```s``` in the signature, hence my concern. I will try to give an example. @chi

Comment: @jam That's a tricky property that should be ensured by parametricity. It's by no means a simple one, so I understand your confusion. Feel free to craft an example, so that we can discuss this point more precisely.

Comment: For me this compiles with no error with the vector package, (im using some  language extensions):
```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Vector.Mutable as VM
class Write s x k v where write :: x -> k -> v -> (ST s) () 
instance Write s (VM.MVector s Int) Int Int where write x k v = VM.write x k v
```

Comment: @jam That's because the type of `write` uses a constraint `Write s x k v`, so these variables are "connected", in a sense. You can observe the connection from the type. Without such a constraint it would be impossible.

Comment: So what is the right way to design stateful monadic typeclasses in Haskell?

Comment: My feeling is that the answer might be "don't put an ```s``` in the typeclass variables". But I don't know, haskell best practices have never been clear to me. Sorry for my rambling

Comment: @jam I'm unsure about that. It depends on the actual goal. You can sometimes change `class C a b where f :: T a b` to `class C a where f :: forall b. T a b` to make `b` independent from `a`.

Comment: I'm with chi here. Parametricity often takes care of what seems to be your concern. The general issue of state management can be a bit trickier, and might be handled using lenses or effect systems. It's hard to make concrete recommendations without a concrete problem.